# Can I simulate a DNS failure from PHP?

Tags: php, http, dns

I am currently building a multi-site content management system for a client which will support a separate domain name per web site. When the web site the domain is pointing to is not found, the client would like to simulate a failure in the browser as evidenced in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the result I would like]

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in PHP. Does anybody have details on this or any advice?

Comment: You can always point your `hosts` file to wrong IP. Not the same thing though

Comment: @E_p That would be great if the sites weren't publicly accessible.

Comment: Host your own DNS server. That would return that error. And point your browser to use that DNS. Does not look like it is a PHP  thing to handle anyway. Why would you need it?

Comment: @E_p That's a great idea but it really pushes the scope of the project. It's meant to be a mechanism if a data discrepancy happens and a domain not registered with the system is pointed to the CMS. I don't understand why they want to do it over a 404 to be honest with you.

Comment: The only way to do it is to host own DNS, And `force` users to use that DNS. As there is no any other way to control that.

Comment: Unless we talking sub-domains, than you can use webserver or php to do routing

Comment: The issue that E_p is alluding to is that the web browser goes to DNS to look up the IP. If it doesn't look up, you get the DNS failure. If it does look up, it accesses the website and that is when PHP kicks in. PHP kicks in long after the DNS lookup takes place. So, you can't really do it with PHP. You'd have to make a fake "Name not found" page that may or may not look like the web browser's built-in name not found page.

Comment: @E_p Ugh, typical luck. Yeah, we're talking sub-domains, as the routing is handled by a micro framework.

Comment: @kainaw Thank you! Wish me luck telling the client this.

Comment: Another option: You *can* customize the 404 page not found page. You can do anything you like with it.

Comment: Looks like the only alternative really.